# Updating a jar client side

Tags: java

I made a simple java program for my father, I created the artifact and he uses it by running the jar file. The jar file has an embedded database in it, SQLite. He found an error in the program when he inputs a space in one of the columns. Is there a way for me to patch the jar without him losing the database?

Comment: So there is only one .jar file and no seperate file for the database?

Comment: How do you write to an embedded database in a Jar file?  The database must be stored externally at some point?

Comment: If there is no change in db structure and if you aren't re-creating db file by code then I don't feel you have to be worried of losing data

Comment: I am using intellij with the database in the resource folder it is embedded. I created the artifact and runs find using the jar file. im no expert so not sure why it is not stored externally

Comment: Arvind, I just have to edit one of the classes that inputs the data into the database. so how can i update or patch that specific class once the jar file has been created